# How to link/navigate through SQL search results in PHP one page at a time

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, filtering, storing-data

I am building an admin type script to view records within a mySQL database. This links in numerous  tables and is all working perfect. I have now added a filter form to allow me to search/filter for records that match specific criteria. Again this works perfect.

The problem I cannot get my head around is this...

For each record I have a link that allows me to go into that record and view more information/perform tasks on the record.

Initially it was simple to have a 'Previous' and 'Next' link for cycling through the records which meant I didnt need to go Back to the search results to go to the previous/next record. It simply +1 or -1 from the current record ID to generate the link.

Now however I am filtering so the records ID's might be 1,3,4,5,8,10,15,30 etc

The problem is now that once I click into any one of the results to view that record I essentially lose the filtering and all of the results.

The only way I can think of achieving this is to pass the filter variables in with the link and redo the filtering every time the View page is loaded, working out where the current record is in the result set and creating a link based on the previous and next records in the result set.

Am I doing this correct or is there a better way?

I have searched but most answers are geared towards the basics of looping through mySQL query results which sounds the same but is very different.

Any advice would be greatlt appreciated!

Comment: what is you database? it may also help to look at a piece of your code

Comment: Sorry its a mySQL, editted the question to show this now. I haven't implemented this part yet. Its more of a "how to do it" question rather than wanting the code checking. Not sure if there is an easier way of remembering the result set and PHP knowing which record it is currently showing and what ID is next/previous. @JonathandosSantos